# Implement Dynamic Programming in this algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

I was provided with an algorithm that would help me solve the following problem:

Take an `NxN` grid. Start at the top left and traverse to the bottom right only going down or right from each node. For example:

`grid = [[0,2,5],[1,1,3],[2,1,1]]`

Imagine this list as a grid:

```
0 2 5
1 1 3
2 1 1
```

Each number you visit you have to add to the running total. In this case there are six different ways to get to the bottom that provide you with a total sum. The algorithm I was given that would work for this and return a list of possible sums is as follows:

```
def gridsums(grid, x, y, memo):
if memo[x][y] is not None:
    return memo[x][y]

if x == 0 and y == 0:
    sums = [0]
elif x == 0:
    sums = gridsums(grid, x, y-1, memo)
elif y == 0:
    sums = gridsums(grid, x-1, y, memo)
else:
    sums = gridsums(grid, x-1, y, memo) + gridsums(grid, x, y-1, memo)

sums = [grid[x][y] + s for s in sums]
memo[x][y] = sums
return sums

def gridsumsfast(grid):
memo = []
for row in grid:
    memo.append([])
    for cell in row:
        memo[-1].append(None)

return gridsums(grid, len(grid[0]) - 1, len(grid) - 1, memo)
```

Indentation is not correct but you get the idea. This works however for a much larger value of N, it does not work well at all. For example up to a N value of 20, it takes to long and on some tests I ran it times out.

Obviously there is a lot of repeat work being done by the main function so how exactly can I implement memoization/dynamic programming with this algorithm? The work is repeated a lot of times giving me grounds to say dynamic programming needs to be implemented however the line: `sum = [grid[x][y] = s for s in sums]` trips me up because `x` and `y` change for each value so I would only have to commit the previous sums into a memo however I cannot quite wrap my head around doing so.

Any guidance in the right direction is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Do you want to return all possible sums (that would be hard because in general there will be a lot of ways to make the traversal)? or do you just want to know the smallest sum?

Comment: I need all, because I need to compare all to a given number depending on what that is. The previous algo works just is very efficient I'm trying to find a way to make the time better with DP

Comment: So you are looking for (essentially) a fast/good way to list out all the possible traversals? (from which you can determine the costs)

Comment: Yes! Thank you for simplifying what I was saying, that's exactly what I need

Comment: List out all the sums of the possible traversals...just so we're clear

Comment: So, you don't care to know what the traversals are... just want to know the sum of the costs of each.  Approximately how big is N?

Comment: N will be up to twenty and each number will be no bigger than 10. I don't need to keep track of which way is which, just need an array of all possible traversed sums in it, yes

Comment: You do realize that you will have up to (38 Choose 19)=35,345,263,800 (non-distinct) sums?  You are sure you want all of them? or do you just want all of the distinct sums?

Comment: Distinct is fine, no need for duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All paths arrive in a cell either from above or from left. If you loop through the grid left to right and top to bottom, you can accumulate the sums from cells you have computed already. The idea is the same as in [TravisJ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27625687/222914).

```
def gridsums(grid):
    previous_row_sums = [set() for _ in grid[0]]
    previous_row_sums[0].add(0) #seed
    for row in grid:
        left_sums = set()
        row_sums = []
        for value, above_sums in zip(row, previous_row_sums):
            old_sums = left_sums | above_sums
            sums = {value + old for old in old_sums}
            row_sums.append(sums)
            left_sums = sums
        previous_row_sums = row_sums
    return sums
```

Comment: @DomFarolino https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset